# Add value to textbox after clicking the "Add" button in VB.net

Tags: vb.net, vb.net-2010

Here is my Part of the coding...what i want is when i clicked the button, the value from the database will be added into the textbox. But what i get when i click the button, the value in the textbox is straight replaced by the new value from the database.
anybody can help me on solving this problem?

```
Private Sub btnAdd_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnAdd.Click

        txtShowDescrip.Text &= cmbDescrip.SelectedItem & ","

        Dim conn As OleDbConnection = New OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=SDP_DB.accdb")
        Dim str As String
        Dim dr As OleDbDataReader
        Dim cmd As OleDbCommand
        Dim total As Integer = 0
        conn.Open()
        str = "Select * From ChargeTable Where Description='" & cmbDescrip.Text & "'"

        cmd = New OleDbCommand(str, conn)
        dr = cmd.ExecuteReader
        dr.Read()
        If dr.HasRows = True Then

            total += dr.Item("PriceRate")
            txtShowRate.Text = "$" & total

        End If
        dr.Close()
        conn.Close()
    End Sub
```

Comment: Omg, read your own post back;

Answer (score 0):

Omg, read your own post back;

... when i clicked the button, the value in the textbox will be added into the textbox. 
But when i click the button, the value in the textbox is straight replaced by the new value.

So what exactly do you want to happen the the button is clicked?

Comment: btw...i need to sum the value from the database while i clicked the add button...but it straight replace the value from the database into the textbox when i click the button

Answer (score 0):

Your currently set the text of the textbox to the new value, if you want to add new stuff you need to use & or &=

```
    Dim nfi As New System.Globalization.NumberFormatInfo()
    nfi.CurrencySymbol = "$"

    dim tot as decimal = total + Decimal.Parse(TextBox1.Text, Globalization.NumberStyles.Any, nfi)


    txtShowRate.Text =  "$" & tot
```

Comment: david..thank you for your answer...but the result from your coding is it display again another value...what i want is sum the value into the textbox...

Answer (score 0):

```
If dr.HasRows = True Then
        total = CType(txtShowRate.Text,Integer) + dr.Item("PriceRate")
        txtShowRate.Text = "$" & total.ToString
End If
```

Answer (score 0):

You may use static declaration ..

```
Static total As Integer = 0
```

Or if you still use `Dim` ..

```
If dr.HasRows = True Then

    total = val(txtShowRate.Text) + dr.Item("PriceRate")
    txtShowRate.Text = "$" & format(total)

End If
```

Comment: erm...thank you matzone...i just tried your code..but still not working...=(